# BoxShadow effect only to the left and bottom of Container in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I was wondering if it is possible to have a shadow effect only to the left and the bottom of a Container like in the snip below? The orange shadow is on the left and the bottom. I'm still short of ideas as to how to bring about this effect. Below are the snip and the code that I've written:

[image]

```
class ProfileLastPub extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
      mainAxisSpacing: 15,
      crossAxisSpacing: 10,
      crossAxisCount: 4,
      staggeredTileBuilder: (index) =>
          StaggeredTile.count(2, index.isEven ? 3 : 2),
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => Card(
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: index.isEven
                ? BorderRadius.only(
                    topRight: Radius.circular(30),
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30))
                : BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(30)),
            side: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 3)),
        elevation: 15,
        shadowColor: Colors.orange,
        child: Image.asset(
          'assets/images/Membership – Platinum.png',
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
      itemCount: 4,
    );
  }
}
```

The output that my code produces. The area marked in red is where I have the shadow which looks very mild.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a Card Widget you try using a Container and edit the decoration property. As an example:

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.red,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only( //Edit the shape here
        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
        topLeft: Radius.circular(10)
    ),
    boxShadow: [
      BoxShadow(
        color: Colors.orange, //Color of the shadow
        spreadRadius: 7, 
        blurRadius: 8,
        offset: Offset(0, 3), //Offset of the shadow
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```